# Transverse Array for Maximum Integer

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

**Update: I know BASIC java, well... basic basic. I do not understand really any of the answers as we are very early in our course. I know this is supposed to be a learning experience, but giving me the answer helped me, as I was able to derive what most of the things meant and LEARNED, as I didn't know "max" or any of that before.**

The question posed to me:

Write a program that creates an array of integer values. Use a for loop to
print the values in the array. Use a second for loop to traverse the array and find
the maximum integer in the array.

My code:

```
public class P3D
    {
    public static void main( String[] args )
        {
        int[] myInt = new int[10];

        myInt[0] = 34;
        myInt[1] = -3;
        myInt[2] = 12;
        myInt[3] = 90;
        myInt[4] = 3;
        myInt[5] = 4;
        myInt[6] = 56;
        myInt[7] = 92;
        myInt[8] = 0;
        myInt[9] = -45;

        for( int x = 0; x < 10; x++ )
            {
            System.out.println( myInt[x] );
            }
        }
    }
```

What would my next for loop be to get the maximum value? I have searched my textbook and the internet extensively.. but cannot seem to find a solution.

This is only a week or two in my AP Computer Science Class. Other classmates are behind me in curriculum, and the teacher usually does not know himself.

Comment: hint: you'll need a variable to store the currentMax

Comment: I don't really understand what you're saying. I am VERY new to java, and haven't learned currentmax.

Comment: currentmax is variable. You might name it as biggestInArray

Comment: Have a look at Collections.max(). I would be surprised if there is not a million results for the right search.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a real-life analogy. Ten people are going to walk by you, each carrying a sign with an integer on it. You have no idea what these integers are going to be in advance, but after the last person walks by, you need to be able to say which integer was the greatest. What would be an easy way to do that?

Hint: let's say the first person walks by with 50, and the next with 45. You're not going to bother to remember the 45, since the 50 will beat it anyway. So effectively, you only need to keep one number in your head at any given time. That should be enough to get you started!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving you the exact solution here is the idea to get it done.

1. Keep a variable that hold the max. in the array
2. Traverse through the array and update the max when it needs to be update.
3. Voila at the end of loop you have max element from the array

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to create another variable, lets call it `max` of type `int` which will be used to store the biggest value we have found. Then all you need to do is create a another `for` loop just like your first one and add some logic. Here is what it will look like:

```
int max = myInt[0]//Assume that the max is the first value

for(int x=1;x<10;x++){//We can skip element 0 because we assumed it to be the max
    if(max<myInt[x]) max=myInt[x];//If the current element is bigger than the assumed max, we assume that element is the max
}
System.out.println("The max is: " + max);//After you finish the loop the value of max must be the biggest integer!
```

Comment: Please delete your answer so that the OP has a chance to work it out for him or herself. Your code looks good, but what's more important here is the learning opportunity.

Comment: Thank you, not sure I fully understand what that all means, but I get the desired output. I'll be curious as to what my classmates to get, if they get it at all. My assumption is our teacher will eventually tell us to skip it.

Comment: @musical_coder My answer clearly explains how it works, its not just handing him the answer. I believe this is a valid and good way to teach people, and it is the methodology I use in real life.

Comment: @user2808966 If you have any questions please ask!

Comment: @musical_coder I have not learned any of this yet, and our book does not contain any reference to it. Our teacher uses material from another teacher's class, and most of the time, things come up we haven't learned.

Comment: @Dgrin91 I appreciate your answer! I studied the code and looked a few things up, and I now know how to use that new code segment. Thanks!

Comment: @Dgrin91: I agree that explaining an example with annotations can be somewhat helpful, but anytime you write out the complete code, you are indeed "handing him the answer". Once user2808966 saw your complete code, he/she lost the opportunity to figure it out for his/herself, which is ultimately the best way to learn anything. IMO, complete code should only be given out if a student isn't understanding a hint like the one I gave above.

Comment: @user2808966 quick test: do you know how to find the smallest value now? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you think through it logically your logic should be something like this

You know you're going through each value of the array one by one.
So you need some way to remember what the current maximum number is.

If your current maximum number is less than the value your for loop is at, then you know your current value is greater than the current maximum, so you replace it.

int curMax = Integer.MIN_VALUE; //Integer.MIN_VALUE gets the lowest possible value an integer can be, therefor, everything in the array MUST be greater than or equal to that value.

Go through the array using your for loop, if the value of myInt[x] > curMax, you set curMax equal to myInt[x].

After the array is finished, curMax = the value of the highest int in the array.

I tried not to give you the code as you wont learn much, but I hope I answered your question fully enough for you to complete it on your own. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with very simple code by using the java API to help:

```
Arrays.sort(myInt); // sort from lowest to highest
int largest = myInt[myInt.length - 1]; // get the last one
```